# New Deep Learning VM deployment resource-level error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am getting the error below while trying to deploy a Google Cloud VM Image, using zone europe-west1-b, GPU NVIDIA Tesla K80, and framework PyTorch 1.4 + fast.ai (CUDA 10.0). Both my global and regional quotas are 1, so I don't think it's a quota issue. Any help would be much appreciated! (P.S.: using the TensorFlow Enterpris 2.1 (CUDA 10.1) framework also gives an error.)

tensorflow-vm-tmpl has resource level errors cs229-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/'. The URL is malformed.","reason":"invalid"}],"message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/'. The URL is malformed.","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/copper-depot-276723/zones/europe-west1-b/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the request, it seems that the error is with the request to the API.

Could you share the code and libraries that you are using?